# Base class using data from derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have a class

```
Class A
{
    uint8_t* queue;
    uint32_t num_elems_queue;
    void DoSomethingWithQueue();
};
```

This class will be my library which will be used by different clients. 
In the client code that used the above class I will have something like.

```
Class B
{
    const uint32_t num_elems = 8;
    uint8_t queue[num_elems];
};
```

Now in order to initialize the data in class A I have two options. One is that I pass data in to class A in constructor such as

```
Class A
{
    A(uint8_t* queue__, uint32_t num_elems_queue__): queue(queue__),num_elems_queue(num_elems_queue__)
    {
    }
    uint8_t* queue;
    uint32_t num_elems_queue;
    void DoSomethingWithQueue();
};
```

The other is that I inherit class B from class A and have pure virtual functions in class A that return pointer to needed data. such as

```
Class A
{

    uint8_t* queue;
    uint32_t num_elems_queue;
    void DoSomethingWithQueue();
    virtual uint32_t get_num_elems_queue() = 0;
    virtual uint8_t* get_queue() = 0;
};

Class B : public A
{
    const uint32_t num_elems = 8;
    uint8_t queue[num_elems];
    uint32_t get_num_elems_queue()
    {
        return num_elems;
    }
    uint8_t* get_queue() 
    {
        return queue
    }
};
```

Now my question is which is the preferred way. I have been told that second method is better but my opinion is that in case of second method I am inheriting not to extend base class but to send data back to the base class. Does this not go against the basic reason why inheritance should be used "To extend the functionality of the class".

EDITED:
I think this situation can be solved by passing "num_elems" to class A. But in general when we have a single class that works on different data it is better to inherit and use the data from the derived class. Correct me if I am wrong. After a little searching I found a similar example from MSDN website:
The code is in VB I am not VB developer but from what I understood scenario is same. 
From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27db6csx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

> Suppose, for example, that you have a large business application that manages several kinds of in-memory lists. One is an in-memory copy of your customer database, read in from a database at the beginning of the session for speed. The data structure might look something like the following:

```
Class CustomerInfo
    Protected PreviousCustomer As CustomerInfo
    Protected NextCustomer As CustomerInfo
    Public ID As Integer 
    Public FullName As String 

    Public Sub InsertCustomer(ByVal FullName As String)
        ' Insert code to add a CustomerInfo item to the list. 
    End Sub 

    Public Sub DeleteCustomer()
        ' Insert code to remove a CustomerInfo item from the list. 
    End Sub 

    Public Function GetNextCustomer() As CustomerInfo
        ' Insert code to get the next CustomerInfo item from the list. 
        Return NextCustomer
    End Function 

    Public Function GetPrevCustomer() As CustomerInfo
        'Insert code to get the previous CustomerInfo item from the list. 
        Return PreviousCustomer
    End Function 
End Class
```

> Your application may also have a similar list of products the user has added to a shopping cart list, as shown in the following code fragment:

```
Class ShoppingCartItem
    Protected PreviousItem As ShoppingCartItem
    Protected NextItem As ShoppingCartItem
    Public ProductCode As Integer 
    Public Function GetNextItem() As ShoppingCartItem
        ' Insert code to get the next ShoppingCartItem from the list. 
        Return NextItem
    End Function 
End Class
```

> **You can see a pattern here: two lists behave the same way (insertions, deletions, and retrievals) but operate on different data types**. Maintaining two code bases to perform essentially the same functions is not efficient. The most efficient solution is to factor out the list management into its own class, and then inherit from that class for different data types:

```
Class ListItem
    Protected PreviousItem As ListItem
    Protected NextItem As ListItem
    Public Function GetNextItem() As ListItem
        ' Insert code to get the next item in the list. 
        Return NextItem
    End Function 
    Public Sub InsertNextItem()
        ' Insert code to add a item to the list. 
    End Sub 

    Public Sub DeleteNextItem()
        ' Insert code to remove a item from the list. 
    End Sub 

    Public Function GetPrevItem() As ListItem
        'Insert code to get the previous item from the list. 
        Return PreviousItem
    End Function 
End Class
```

> The ListItem class needs only to be debugged once. Then you can build classes that use it without ever having to think about list management again. For example:

```
Class CustomerInfo
    Inherits ListItem
    Public ID As Integer 
    Public FullName As String 
End Class 
Class ShoppingCartItem
    Inherits ListItem
    Public ProductCode As Integer 
End Class
```

Comment: Inheritance means `A isa B`. If it fulfills that requirement use inheritance. Otherwise do not. Besides why not use std::vector.

Comment: You should be consistent in your code formatting.

Comment: @EdHeal I thought vectors are slower than arrays. I use them only when needed. Maybe I forgot to mention that this is code for a 32bit ARM cortex M0 processor. By using arrays I gain speed.

Comment: This should not be the reason to use inheritance. Unless you want to use B as a kind of A then inheritance is not really appropriate.

Comment: @user3866197 No, vectors aren't slower than arrays. Whoever told you that was playing a practical joke. And it worked.

Comment: To be fair they can be. But just set the size to the appropriate initial size then they are the same.

Comment: I think we are going off topic. Original question was is it necessary to use inheritance here. Given that Class B has data that class A needs. The only thing that I picked up is that in this case it maybe better to not use inheritance, rather pass the data in the constructor of class A ?

Answer (score 0):

It is usualy the superior option to derive class `B` from `A`

For example:

```
class Vehicle
{
public:
    int WheelCount;
};

class Truck : public Vehicle
{
public:
    int LadderHeight;
};
```

A `Truck` is also a `Vehicle`. Therefore you use derivation. The property `WheelCount` will also be available in `Truck`.

Derivation in general means, something **is** another thing. In this example, a Truck is a Vehicle. You can also say that a MonsterTruck is a Truck (i.e. multiple derivance).

*Despite the fact that you could use `std::vector` or `std::list` for that, but I don't think that is the question here. I just thought it was worth mentioning...*

Answer (score 0):

> Now my question is which is the preferred way.

Answers will be heavily influenced by opinion and by other factors such as the coding style of the rest of the program or details of the specific problem you're solving.

So just do something that works and which passes code review, and then pay attention to how well it works over the life of the project. Then next time you have to make a similar design decision you can make it based on experience and with full knowledge of the specific project.

---

> The most efficient solution is to factor out the list management into its own class, and then inherit from that class for different data types:

That statement is far too broad, and C++ in particular has many more tools for design than VB. Consider that C++ has a generic `list` type as well, and using it doesn't involve inheritance at all.

---

There are some other implementation options.

1. Your class `A` currently uses implementation inheritance for both data members and the `DoSomethingWithQueue()` member function. You can reduce the implementation inheritance by eliminating the data members.

   ```
   class A
   {
     // A has no data members
   public:
     void DoSomethingWithQueue(); // implemented purely in terms of the virtual functions
   protected:
     virtual uint32_t get_num_elems_queue() = 0;
     virtual uint8_t* get_queue() = 0;
   };
   ```
2. You can also completely avoid inheritance:

   ```
   template<typename QueueContainer>
   void DoSomethingWithQueue(QueueContainer const &qc);

   class B {
   public:
     uint32_t get_num_elems_queue();
     uint8_t* get_queue();
   };

   B b;
   DoSomethingWithQueue(b);
   ```

   The above assumes the same basic interface for `B` as you specified, though there could be better designs for that as well. E.g., you might want it to conform to the standard Container concept rather than having custom `get_queue()` and `get_num_elements_queue()` members. Then you might even be able to use a standard Container instead of defining your own `class B`.